# Laravel fetch data by something else than id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm totally new to laravel and I don't know if it can be done but I saw that in the controller I can display data of a specific 'id' with this in my api.php:

```
Route::get('books/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\BooksController@getBookById');
```

And this in my BookController.php :

```
public function getBookByAuthor($id) {
    $book = Books::find($id);
    if (is_null($book)){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Book Not Found.'], 404);
    }
    return response()->json($book::find($id), 200);
}
```

I'm using Angular for the front and I have a searchbar to search by 'title' of a book, so in my database I have a column 'title' and I want to fetch data by 'title' instead of 'id'.
Is it possible, and if yes how?

Comment: You can perform a [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses) and then [retrieve a single row](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table). Please try that and update the question if you run into any issues

Comment: Using the ID like this isn't the easiest way to proceed in Laravel.  Have a look at the documentation for [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) and for your use case above [explicit route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you're wanting to retrieve the book based on user input...? You can inject the request in your method. Also you don't need to explicitly handle 404 and response codes.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Book;

public function getBookByAuthor(Request $request): Response
{
$input = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash' // validate
    ]);
    return Book::where('title', 'like', "%{$input['title']}%")
        ->firstOrFail();
}
```

[Validation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)